# How to search for matching items in a list?

Tags: list, haskell, abstract-data-type

I'm doing an exercise to practice for my exam tomorrow.
The text tells me to implement a database to a library, to define `Item`s that can be books or magazines. To each book I save the Name + Author. To each `Magazine` I save the name:

```
 data Item = Book String String
      | Magazine String
      deriving(Show)

data Requisition = Req String Item

type Database = [Requisition]

exDB :: Database
exDB = [Req "John" (Book "PF" "HS"),Req "Jay"(Book "Apple" "Steve Jobs"),Req "Francis"(Magazine "Forbes")]

books :: Database -> String -> [Item]
books db name = {-- what's next?-}
```

Now, I need to create a function named `books :: Database -> String -> [Item]`, that searches by name on my database and gives me the books that person requested.

how do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

This is fairly straightforward using the `filter` function:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

It takes a condition to apply to each element of a list, then returns the list of all elements that meet that condition.  In your case, you want to look up what books have been requested by a given person.  You can break this down into two problems:

1. Find all requests for a given person
2. Find all books in a `Requisition` list

To solve the first, we say

```
requestsFromPerson :: Database -> String -> Database
requestsFromPerson db name = filter matchesName db
    where
        matchesName (Req name' item) = name == name'
```

The second step can also be done with `filter`, but I'm going to let you fill in the implementation

```
onlyBooks :: Database -> Database
onlyBooks db = filter ??? db
```

Then you can combine these two:

```
books db name = onlyBooks (requestsFromPerson db name)
```

So all you have to do is fill in the `???` for `onlyBooks` and this should work!  Hint: pattern matching is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

```
books db name = [... | Req n b@(Book _ _) <- db, n==name]
```

With list comprehensions, mismatched items are just skipped over. Patterns may be nested.